# Django.db.utils.ProgramingError Relation doesn't exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations, django-database, django-postgresql

I am using Django3 and Postgres as Database, I clone the old project using Django and postgres, I cloned and setup the virtual environment for my project.
At the time of runserver, its throws me the error of

```
 Django.db.utils.ProgramingError realtion "Table name" doesn't exist
```

There was the migrations file in the project when I cloned it, but I removed them, so can create my own, but this error still there, even I remove the migrations folder, but its still there and can't create my own migrations and not even start the server.

I tried it with cloned migrations files and without it but can't runserver

Answer (score 0):

1. Run this command **python manage.py showmigrations**
2. Remove the actual migration files
3. Go through each of your projects apps migration folder and remove
   everything inside, except for the ****init**.py** file
4. Then run **python manage.py makemigrations**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I tried it too, but the same response, I tried with the new db to setup but the same answer and that sucks